# Laravel - leftJoin and reference to elements

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, left-join

I have the following tables in my db:

**connections** 
id 
owner_id

**owners** 
id 
first_name

**ConnectionsController.php**

```
$connections = DB::table('connections')
            ->leftJoin('owners', 'owners.id', '=', 'connections.owner_id')
            ->get();

return view('connections.index', ['connections' => $connections]);
```

How I can refer in forearch loop to owners.first_name?
I have something like this in my **connections/index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($connections as $element)
    {{ $element->owners->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

But it results in "Undefined property". What should I put in my foreach loop to get owners.first_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Eloquent. Define a [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) in `Connection` model:

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Owner::class);
}
```

Load connections with owners:

```
$connections = Connection::with('owner')->get();
```

Display the data:

```
@foreach($connections as $element)
    {{ $element->owner->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

If not all connections have an owner, do this:

```
@foreach($connections as $element)
    {{ optional($element->owner)->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

Or:

```
@foreach($connections as $element)
    {{ $element->owner ? $element->owner->first_name : 'There is no owner' }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Alexey Mezenin, you're 100% right. But using “with” to build relations is it possible to make a “where” in the query? E.g. SELECT * FROM connections LEFT JOIN owners ON owners.id = connections.owner_id WHERE owners.first_name LIKE 'test’? Because I tried and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Patryk if you want to filter relation use [eager loading constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). If you want to filter connection by relation, use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 1):

Joins "join" both tables into a single row. You're referencing `->owners` object which doesn't exists since properties of both `owners` and `connections` are joined into a single row.

This should work:

```
@foreach($connections as $element)
    {{ $element->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

But you should also see Alexey Mezenin solution which is the idiomatic Laravel way of doing this and will make your life easier in the long run.